# Can all systems be described by differential/difference equations?

Tags: filters, linear-systems, non-linear

All LCCODEs (linear, constant-coefficient ordinary differential equation) with initial rest conditions describe causal LTI systems (is this a correct statement?)

- Is the converse true, i.e. can **all** causal LTI systems be described by LCCODEs with initial rest? If not, what are the necessary/sufficient conditions?

It seems trivial that arbitrary differential/difference equations describe some sort of system (is that also true?)

- Again, is the converse true, i.e. can we describe any **arbitrary** systems with (possibly
  nonlinear/variable-coefficient/partial, without restriction on initial
  conditions) differential equations? If not, what are the necessary/sufficient conditions?

Answer (score 2):

No the converse is not true in general.

Take for example the discrete-time **ideal lowpass filter** with impulse response

$$ h[n] = \frac{ \sin( \omega_c n) }{ \pi n } ~~~,~~~-\infty < n <\infty$$

which describes an **LTI** system but it does not correspond to a difference equation of any kind. Indeed $h[n]$ is derived based on the inverse discrete-time Fourier transform of the filter frequency response;

$$ H(\omega) = \begin{cases} {1 ~~~,~~~ |\omega| < \omega_c \\ 0 ~~~,~~~ \text{ otherwise } }\end{cases} $$

$$h[n] = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} H(\omega) e^{j\omega n} d\omega $$

Comment: Why is there no difference equation? There is one with infinitely many terms. Is it implementable? No, but it does exist.

Comment: Indeed so! I just probably referred to te general acceptance. As one usually either solves an LCCDE to get the impulse response or uses it to compute the output from input but in this case you neither solve for $h[n]$ which is first obtained from the Fourier transform inversion nor use such LCCDE to make any computations, but merely construct an uncomputable (infinite order!) LCDDE. Probably that's why it's accepted that there are no corresponding LCCDE for such infinetely-long yet FIR (*finite* impulse response) filters...

Comment: I understand your point. However, I would say that *existence* (in a Platonist's Heaven) is one thing, and *realizability* (using pencil & paper, hardware or software) is another. But this is obviously a matter of taste.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo probably so...